# Simulation only code and Synthesis only code in QuestaSim

Tags: vhdl, simulation, questasim

Pragma exist to tell the synthesis tool to ignore lines or blocks of code, using this:

```
-- synthesis translate_off
  ... code to ignore
-- synthesis translate on
```

But are there pragma that can be used to tell the simulator to ignore certain lines or blocks of code as they are intended for synthesis only and not be considered by the simulator tool?

**EDIT:**

OK here is an example just to make a point, a counter in synthesis counts upto 100,000. In simulation I need the simulation to run faster so in simulation the counter shall only run upto 100.

Comment: Would you mind to [edit] your question and add, why you need this? An example would shed some light on it. Can't you divide your design into separate source files for the same purpose?

Comment: OK here is an example just to make a point, a counter in synthesis counts upto 100,000. In simulation I need the simulation to run faster so in simulation the counter shall only run upto 100.

Comment: I don't think there is any pragma like that as it facilitates synth-sim mismatches beating the purpose of design. WRT your query, just use existing constructs, for eg: put a macro or so: `ifdef SYNTHESIS `define COUNT_MAX 100000 `else `define COUNT_MAX 100

Comment: There's modifying a design with generate statements and configuration declarations describing binding for simulation. The granularity of the former is concurrent statements the latter entities and their architectures. There's also the use of generics for control flow.

Comment: I guess using generics is really the only thing can/should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems we are missing something like an `else` branch in such conditional translation. And standardization in general. Oh, well.

Consider using the freedom of formatting the source code:

```vhdl
-- other code
constant N : integer := 100000
-- synthesis translate_off
  - 99900
-- synthesis translate on
  ;
```